Azure: The nuget command failed with exit code(null) and error() - packages failed to restore
In Azure we have an pipeline which restores the nuget-packages of our C#-solution:
- task: NuGetCommand@2
    inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        includeNuGetOrg: true

The pipeline has always run smoothly so far. One day, however, we get the following error messages in the console:
##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(null) and error()
##[error]Packages failed to restore


There are no further error messages in the console to give us an indication of the cause.
We use no caching.
Locally, in Visual Studio, the restore-command works well.

Has anyone an idea what´s wrong?

It seems the latest version of nugetCommand2 is broken - have seen a github thread for it
revert your command to the latest working version - for us its - 2.238.1
so your command would be
- task: NuGetCommand@2.238.1
    inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        includeNuGetOrg: true


Yes Latest NuGetCommand is broken.

There is a GitHub issue has reported the same problem occurs on the latest version (2.244.1) of NuGetCommand task. Looks like, there is defect on the task version 2.244.1.
As mentioned in the GitHub issue, you can force specify the task to a previous version that can work fine. For example.
- task: NuGetCommand@2.238.1
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
      feedsToUse: 'select'
      vstsFeed: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
      includeNuGetOrg: true


